# Fix checkboxes in form rows lead to odd behavior for later form row elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image: Issue w/ checkboxes inline w/ form elements]

I'm trying to figure out if there's a fix for this that doesn't involve me adjusting css for this specific case. I want my inline checkbox / labels to not create the scenario where the padding / margin's don't match the other fields and causing future fields to be moved up into those extra spaces. Ideally in this picture Notes for purchase order should start on the next line and not below "Add to existing PO".

Here is my html

```html
<div class="row">
  <form>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="addToPO">
                                        Add to existing PO
                                    </label>
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="addToPO">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-10">
        <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
          <option selected>Choose...</option>
          <option>...</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputSupplier">Supplier</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSupplier">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputSupNum">Supplier #</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSupNum">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputSupName">Supplier Contact Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSupName">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputSupPhone">Supplier Contact Phone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSupPhone">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputSupEmail">Supplier Contact Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSupEmail">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="addToPO">
                                        Add to existing PO
                                    </label>
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="addToPO">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="PONotes">Notes for Purchase Order</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="PONotes" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I also have tried to put notes for purchase order into a seperate form-row but that has no effect on this issue either.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is I was referencing markup from version 4.4.1 instead of the 3.4 bootstrap version I was using. Form-row is not available in 3.4 and thus it doesn't work as intended.